# Computed function not callable for date conversion

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to convert a firebase timestamp to month abbreviation day, year format with the time in parentheses (e.g., 11/4/2021 (time)).

I have the firebase timestamp and I thought I would be able to use a computed function, but I get the vetur warning "This expression is not callable.   Type 'String' has no call signatures."

I have only gotten to trying to get the month, date, and year.

```
<template>
<div>{{ convertDate(timestamp) }}
</template>
<script>
 export default {
computed: {

 convertDate(time) {
    let month = time.getUTCMonth() + 1; 
    let day = time.getUTCDate();
    let year = time.getUTCFullYear();

    return month + " " + day + "," + year;
  },
 },
};
```

Comment: You are trying to use Date object methods on a non Date object. Create a Date object from `time` first

Comment: Would that mean I could in convertDate(timestamp.toDate())? (This is being handled in a component with data passed in via prop, and I'm not sure how to work with the data before it hits the computed property function)